# Solaris shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

I am writing a script to ftp some files using some rules. But I have problems with the scripts ftp session creation.

below is the shell script I am using right now.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/ericsson/nin/charging/archive
date=`(/usr/bin/perl -e '($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time()-24*60*60);printf "%4d%02d%02d", $year+1900,$mon+1,$mday;')`
movedFile=`ls | grep $date`
HOST=xxxx
USER=xxxx
PASSWD=xxxxx
for i in $movedFile; 
do
    echo $date >> trial.txt
    echo "Uploading file $i" >> trial.txt
    ftp -n $HOST
    quote USER $USER
    quote PASS $PASSWD
    binary
    cd TEMP
    put $i
    quit
    END_SCRIPT
    echo "kk" 
done
```

the problem is. It is unable to trigger quote commands of ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it is unable to be seen in the comments. here is the correct answer worked my situation

```
cd xxxx 
date=(/usr/bin/perl -e '($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time()-24*60*60‌​);printf "%4d%02d%02d", $year+1900,$mon+1,$mday;') 
movedFile=ls | grep $date 
HOST=xxxx 
USER=xxxx 
PASSWD=xxxx 
for i in $movedFile; 
do 
   echo $date >> xxxx.log 
   echo $i >> xxxx.log 
   ftp -n $HOST <<End-Of-Session user "$USER" "$PASSWD" 
   binary 
   cd TEMP 
   put $i 
   quit 
   End-Of-Session 
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [bash Here Documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). The syntax you're looking for is:

```
  ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
  quote USER $USER
  quote PASS $PASSWD
  binary
  cd TEMP
  put $i
  quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: I got this is working for me. !!
 
     #!/bin/bash
     cd xxxx
     date=`(/usr/bin/perl -e  '($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time()-24*60*60);printf "%4d%02d%02d", $year+1900,$mon+1,$mday;')`
     movedFile=`ls | grep $date`
     HOST=xxxx
     USER=xxxx
     PASSWD=xxxx
     for i in $movedFile;
     do
        echo $date >> xxxx.log
        echo $i >> xxxx.log
        ftp -n $HOST <<End-Of-Session
        user "$USER" "$PASSWD"
        binary
        cd TEMP
        put $i
        quit
        End-Of-Session
     done

Comment: @OlgunKaya: don't even try to post code in comments, there's no support for that. If the solution you found is different from using here-documents, post it as an answer.

Comment: I would like to do so if the system allow it before my reputition is less than 100